# Get data from a Symfony controller action with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-routing

I have a simple showAction to show a user's information:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/{id}", name="show_user", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Method("GET")
 *
 * @param User $user
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function showAction(User $user)
{
    return $this->render('user/showUser.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));
}
```

I try to get the information with AJAX to display it in a seperate div:

```
$('.showUser').click(function (e) {

    var getUrl = Routing.generate('show_user', {'id': $(this).attr('id')});
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url:  getUrl,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#userdetails").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

My list of users overview in html:

```
<table class="table-title table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Age</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for user in users  %}
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>
            <button id="{{ user.id }}" type="button" class="deleteUser btn btn-lg btn-danger">Delete</button>
            <button id="{{ user.id }}" type="button" class="showUser btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="displayUser col-sm-4">
    {% include 'user/showUser.html.twig' %}
</div>
```

And my showUser template to display the selected user:

```
<div id="userdetails">
    {{ dump(user) }}
</div>
```

What currently is happening is that when I load the page, the `{{ dump(user) }}` contains an array of all the users, and is not empty. When I then click on the show button to display the one user's information the `{{ dump(user)}}` does change to show the correct information.

Also when I change `{{ dump(user) }}` to be `{{ user.name }} - {{ user.age }}`, and reload the page I get the error:

> Key "name" for array with keys "0, 1" does not exist in
>   user/showUser.html.twig at line 2

Can somebody help me? Explain to me what I am doing wrong? I think there is also something wrong with my ajax call, I have never used ajax before, and I have created this based on samples I managed to find, but further than this I don't get.

All I want is to display the user's information in a div when clicking on the user's show button.

Comment: probably you don't need to include `{% include 'user/showUser.html.twig' %}` because you're loading details via ajax

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

I changed my ajax function:

```
$('.showUser').click(function() {
    var getUrl = Routing.generate('show_user', {'id': $(this).attr('id')});
    $.get(getUrl, function (data) {
            $(".userdetails").html(data);
    });
});
```

I removed the twig include (also what Peter Popelyskho said in the comments) and paste the div that was in the showUser.html in its place:

```
<table class="table-title table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Age</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        {% for user in users  %}
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.age }}</td>
        <td>
            <button id="{{ user.id }}" type="button" class="deleteUser btn btn-lg btn-danger">Delete</button>
            <button id="{{ user.id }}" type="button" class="showUser btn btn-lg btn-primary">Show</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="userdetails"></div>
```

Inside my `user/showUser.html.twig` template I have: `{{ user.name}} - {{ user.age }}`.

And it looks good!

If anybody thinks there is a better way or a more convenient way, please feel free to show me, I want to learn as good as possible.